# Are varifocal glasses a good option for pc use?

Tags: work-environment

I am thinking of getting varifocal glasses however I have heard that they may not be suitable for long term pc use. Does anyone have any experience of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are OK for quick/short uses of the PC but not suitable (to my oppinion) for long uses like full working days et cetera.

Because the "reading" part of the glasses is on the lower side, you will tilt your head up (as in looking at the ceiling) to read the highest parts of the screen. Resulting in an uncomfortable neck / eyes.

It makes sense when you think about it, The varifocal part is meant for reading things like books which you hold flat (horizontal) making it perfect for varifocal glasses. Computerscreens however are vertically positioned.

I recommend getting special "computer glasses". worked like a charm for me :)